# How to invoke a generator function a second time with different parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to pass different parameters to a generator function when I call `next()`?

```
function *random (firstParameter, secondParameter = undefined, thirdParameter = undefined) {
  yield firstParameter
  yield secondParameter + thirdParameter
}

let arbitrary = random(1)
console.log(arbitrary.next()) // 1
console.log(arbitrary.next(undefined, 2, 3)) // Expected: 5, got: NaN
```

`secondParameter` and `thirdParameter` are not available at the first `yield` in my application.

Comment: Those are arguments of the `random(1, …)` call. What you pass into `next` will be the result of the `yield` expression.

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: @Bergi, problem is, `secondParameter` and `thirdParameter` are not available at the first yield in my application.

Comment: No, please tell us why you think you need them to be available there. You're obviously using generators wrong, but if you don't tell us what you want to use them for we cannot tell you what solution would be appropriate.

Comment: I have a service function for a controller that should return different values when called two times. The first part/yield of the code is not aware of the second part/yield. But I guess my question has already been answered: It's not possible in the way I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the it is meaningless to assign `undefined` as a default value to the function arguments. However the main problem is that, you can return only a single value with the `.next()` method of the iterator. So in order to perform this task purposefully you may do as follows;

```js
function *random (firstParameter, secondParameter = undefined, thirdParameter = undefined) {
  [secondParameter,thirdParameter] = yield firstParameter;
  yield secondParameter + thirdParameter;
}

var arbitrary = random(1);
console.log(arbitrary.next().value); // 1
console.log(arbitrary.next([2,3]).value); // Expected: 5, got: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the generator while calling it.

Instead, you could get a new [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) object by calling the [generator function `function *`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) with other parameters.

```js
function *random (firstParameter, secondParameter = undefined, thirdParameter = undefined) {
    yield firstParameter;
    yield secondParameter + thirdParameter;
}

let arbitrary = random(1);
console.log(arbitrary.next()); // 1
console.log(arbitrary.next()); // NaN

let arbitrary2 = random(undefined, 2, 3);
console.log(arbitrary2.next()); // undefined
console.log(arbitrary2.next()); // 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with this solution is that I have two unnecessary `next` calls: 1.: `NaN`, 2.: `undefined`. **Update**: I would have one extra `next` call because `NaN` is not needed.

Comment: maybe it's better to change the organisation of the generator.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Without knowing what you want to do, I don't really know if the structure of your generator is the correct one (and I don't even know if you really need a generator). 
But what about something like this?

```js
function *random (firstParameter, secondParameter = undefined, thirdParameter = undefined) {
  yield firstParameter
  yield secondParameter + thirdParameter
}

let arbitrary = random(1, 2, 3);
console.log(arbitrary.next()); // 1
console.log(arbitrary.next()); // 5
console.log(arbitrary.next()); // undefined
```

**EDITED**: If you don't have your other parameters available immediately, you need to instantiate again your generator. You instance your generator at the beginning, and then you cannot change it. So you may do something like this:

```js
function *random (firstParameter, secondParameter = undefined, thirdParameter = undefined) {
  if(firstParameter) yield firstParameter
  else  yield secondParameter + thirdParameter
}

let arbitrary = random(1);
console.log(arbitrary.next()); // 1
let arbitrary2 = random(undefined, 2, 5);
console.log(arbitrary2.next()); // 7
```

Comment: Thank you. `secondParameter` and `thirdParameter` are not available at the first `yield` in my application. I can't supply them upfront.

Comment: @Julian ok I got you, I updated the answer to show that case as well, but tbo I don't really understand the usage of your generator, and also why you really need a generator implemented in this way. A simple function looks more than enough to me in this way